# What happens when you die in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

What are the penalties upon death? I know money is lost, but how much? Is it a percentage of money in hand, or is it based on level? Are stats affected? How much progress do you lose? Do you lose any items in your inventory? Do the enemies reset? Do you go to the nearest checkpoint or the last one triggered (with the "saving" Borderlands logo)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you run out of health points in Borderlands 2 you enter a 'Last Stand'-style mode, on your knees and able to crawl very slowly. If you manage to get a kill with your parting shots (or an enemy you set on fire/acid/shock burns down on its own) you can gain a second wind, reviving yourself with a bit of health.

Alternatively a team mate can revive you, similar to in other first person shooters (ie: Left 4 Dead)

If you are not revived in time, you will die and be reconstructed at your last [New-U Station](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/New-U_Station), for which you will be charged a reconstruction fee. The fee for respawning at a New-U station costs 7% of a character's money. For example, if the character carries $1,000, the fee would be $70.

Answer (score 25):

A lot of questions were asked here about the inevitable death you will experience in borderlands 2.

**What are the penalties upon death?**

- Money loss,
- Long respawn animation
- Respawn at the closest New-U station ( could be far away )
- Enemies have their health and shield replenished.
- And if the station was a long way away, some enemies might respawn.

**I know money is lost, but how much? Is it a percentage of money in hand, or is it based on level?**

7% of the money you have on hand is lost.

**Are stats affected?**

No

**How much progress do you lose?**

Define progress.  If you or your entire party dies at the same time against a boss, you will have to do the boss fight over.   If you are on a timed quest and you die, you will still have the remaining time left to try and complete the quest.  There is no penalty for quests that have you discover / collect / kill / talk to someone / etc. if you die mid quest.

**Do you lose any items in your inventory?**

No, In fact, your ammo will respawn.

**Do the enemies reset?**

It depends on the time it takes to get back to that enemy which killed you (as mentioned above). Loot chests will however not respawn, and some items may despawn. Mostly whites.

**Do you go to the nearest checkpoint or the last one triggered (with the "saving" Borderlands logo)?**

Yes or the nearest new-u station if you haven't triggered any save station.

Comment: Boss health respawns upon death when you play solo or if your whole party dies.

Comment: And if you exit the game and get back in you are spawning to the fast travel portal from that location... and that is really a pain in the ...... when you're really far. You have to kill monsters "again" to get back where you were. Personally, worst saving system ever !

Comment: Not all of my ammo was refilled. Are you sure ammo is refilled? And does it matter which type of death it is?

Comment: I calculated that it restores 0.31999997 of each type of ammo.

Answer (score 7):

Death typically begins with a top-down, third-person perspective centered on your ragdoll corpse:

[image: top-down, third-person perspective centered on your ragdoll corpse]

Once your corpse has phased out, you enter the respawn vortex: a visual intermission until you are recon(digi)structed at a New-U Station:

[image: the respawn vortex]

Visually, a signal travels down the New-U Station antenna and your body is reconstructed:

[image: signal travels down antenna]

[image: recon(digi)struction]

> Do you go to the nearest checkpoint or the last one triggered (with the "saving" Borderlands logo)?

The New-U Station is the last one you activated. I guess the nearest one in the area if you haven't activated one in the area. If you haven't visited one for a minute, exiting the respawn vortex triggers an autosave.

Your health and shields are fully restored. You lose enemy [aggro](https://wowwiki-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Aggro).

> What are the penalties upon death? I know money is lost, but how much? Is it a percentage of money in hand, or is it based on level?

You lose 7% of your money.

[image: Reconstruction fee notification]

You lose stacks (such as [Anarchy](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Anarchy_(Gaige))). 0.31999997 of capacity of each type of ammo is restored, except for (rocket) launcher and grenade ammo.

[image: ammo restored]

If your body did not become a ragdoll upon death, ammo is not restored and stacks are not lost.

> How much progress do you lose?

Depends on how far you were from the New-U Station.

> Do you lose any items in your inventory?

No.

> Do the enemies reset?

Raid bosses regenerate all health upon [TPK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_party_kill).